# Include Namespace in TypeScript errors?

Tags: typescript, backbone.js, module, namespaces

We're in the process of converting our JS app to TypeScript. When we fetch data from our servers, sometimes we leave it as a plain JSON object, and sometimes we convert it to a Backbone model. We would like to differentiate between these types everywhere. Ideally we would refer to these two types as `Backend.Foo` and `Backbone.Foo`. And when we try to use one in place of the other ideally we would get an error that says "Type 'Backend.Foo' is not assignable to type 'Backbone.Foo'." and *not* an error that says "Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'Foo'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated."

Currently our setup is as follows:

```
// models/foo.ts
export default Foo extends Backbone.Model { ... }

// types/backend/foo.ts
export default interface Foo { ... }

// types/backend.ts
import Foo from "types/backend/foo"
export { Foo }
```

This allows us to do the following:

```
import * as Backend from "types/backend"
import Foo from "models/foo"

let backboneFoo: Foo
let backendFoo: Backend.Foo
```

But if we add:

```
backendFoo = backboneFoo
backboneFoo = backendFoo
```

We get the error: "Type 'Foo' is not assignable to type 'Foo'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated."

We could also re-export our the Backbone models in `models.ts`, so that we can do `import * as Backbone from "models"`, but that wouldn't solve the error message.

Can we get the desired behavior using TypeScript namespaces?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the models and types correctly with "import Foo from "types/backend/foo"? should it be relative like`import Foo from './foo'`?

Comment: Also, try to avoid default export. Use named export 99% of the time.

Comment: I think we jury-rigged Webpack to allow absolute imports rather than relative paths, so that's not an issue. Why are default exports a bad idea?

Comment: There are several reasons. e.g.: https://github.com/unional/typescript-guidelines/blob/master/pages/default/modules.md
and https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly do you want? I re-read your question but not sure what you actually want. Better compile error on TS?